# Kubuntu 15.04 - arrow in the scrollbar

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, scrollbar

is there a way to enable the little up and down arrows on the top and bottom (respectively) of the scroll bar? Some people are so used to it and miss it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ kcmshell5 breezestyleconfig
```

Or, alternatively, go to System Settings > Application Style > Widget Style > Configure